# error with crontab running ruby script

Tags: ruby, macos, cron

Hope you can help me with my problem.

I implemented a script with ruby that running manually works perfectly.

But running in crontab with the line like `*/1 * * * * cd /Users/diogo/workspace/outros/crawler_trf/ && /Users/diogo/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.3.0@crawler/ruby get_news.rb >> /tmp/crawler_trf.out` I got this error:

```
/Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:882:in `rescue in block in connect': Failed to open TCP connection to www.folhadirigida.com.br:80 (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known) (SocketError)
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:319:in `open_http'
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:737:in `buffer_open'
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:212:in `block in open_loop'
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `catch'
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:210:in `open_loop'
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:151:in `open_uri'
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:717:in `open'
from /Users/diogo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
from get_news.rb:6:in `read_data'
from get_news.rb:44:in `<main>'
```

The script file has the following code...

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'mail'

def read_data
  page        = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.folhadirigida.com.br/fd/Satellite/concursos/noticias-TRFRJES-area-de-apoio-2016-2000153335216/'))
  title       = page.css('#tblResult').css('tr')[1].css('a').first.text rescue nil
  message     = page.css('#tblResult').css('tr')[1].text rescue nil

  file_name   = 'trf'
  last_title  = File.open("/tmp/#{file_name}", 'r') { |file| file.read } rescue nil

  if title && last_title != title
    send_email(title, message)

    File.open("/tmp/#{file_name}", 'w') { |file| file.write(title) }
  else
    send_email("Nada novo", "")
  end
end

def send_email(title, message)
  Mail.defaults do
    delivery_method :smtp, {
      :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
      :port => 587,
      :domain => 'gmail.com',
      :user_name => 'myemail',
      :password => 'mypass',
      :authentication => :plain,
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
    }
  end

  Mail.deliver do
    to 'myemail'
    from 'Concursos - Novidades TRF <myemail>'
    subject 'Novidade sobre o TRF'
    content_type 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
    body "<h1>#{title}</h1>#{message}"
  end
end

read_data
```

If I execute `curl` + the url works perfectly... I dont know what is happening. Please I need some explanation and a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, sounds like a DNS problem when the script runs as cron.

I would try to `require "resolv-replace.rb"` at the top of your script, like it's described [here](http://www.subelsky.com/2014/05/fixing-socketerror-getaddrinfo-name-or.html).

Later at home I give it a try and I will test it on my mac.